# How can I delete record from table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, join

I have three tables

Table 1 **supplier** (`sno, sname, city`)

```
1, ahmad, jeddah
```

Table 2 **parts** (`pno, pname, color`)

```
1, laptop, red
```

Table 3 **supplier_parts_shipment** (`shno, sno, pno, date`)

```
1, 1, 1, 2014
```

I need to delete shipment where city='jeddah'and color='red' - how to do this?

```
  1  delete from supplier_parts_shipment
  2  where sno in (select sno from supplier where city='jeddah')
  3  and pno(select pno from parts where color='red')
  4* and (sno=sno) and (pno=pno)
SQL> /
and pno(select pno from parts where color='red')
        *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: Re-read your third line again

Comment: This is for **Oracle**, judging from the `ORA-....` error message, **NOT** for (Microsoft) SQL Server - updated the tags accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
delete from supplier_parts_shipment
where sno in (select sno from supplier where city='jeddah')
and pno in (select pno from parts where color='red');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
3  and pno in (select pno from parts where color='red')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 delete from supplier_parts_shipment as A
 where A.sno in 
 (select B.sno from supplier as B, supplier_parts_shipment  as C, parts as D
  where B.city='jeddah' and D.color='red' and C.sno=B.sno and C.pno=D.pno)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 delete sps from supplier_parts_shipment as sps
 join supplier as sup on sps.sno = sup.sno
 join  parts as prt on sps.pno = prt.pno
 where sup.city = 'jeddah' AND prt.color = 'red'
```

and in your query in is missing on line3

and pno in (select pno from parts where color='red')